# sorting a Matrix in Matlab to a vector

Tags: matlab

I have this problem that I need to sort a matrix in MATLAB, and i need to sort it decently in one vector with advantage for equal values by row, and i need the index as well.

```
input: A= [ 9 9 8 ; 9 8 7; 9 7 6];
output: B= [ 9 9 9 9 8 8 7 7 6];
Index= [ 1 4 2 3 7 5 8 6 9];
```

Comment: What does `Index` represent ? I don't understand what's the use of it.

Comment: what do you mean by _equal values by row_? you know that the matrix have to be rectangular, right?

Comment: i mean when you have i.e 8 in first and second row, it should be chosen from first row ans so on .

Comment: i need to determine from which row we choose this value, as in my example in the question.

Comment: How can you determine from where the 8 come ? I think it is impossible but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact the matrix with a vector of row numbers:

```
At = A.' % since you want to iterate over the rows you need to transpose the matrix first
r = repmat(1:size(A,1),[size(A,2) 1]);
[A_sorted] = sortrows([At(:) r(:)],-1)
```

`r` gives you a vector of the row number of every element in `A` (which is the column number in `At`). Then `sortrows` sorts the rows of `[At r(:)]` by the first column, keeping the row number in the second column aligned with the same element. The result is a 2-column matrix, where the first column is the sorted vector (which was a matrix before), and the second the original row of the element in the first column in `A`:

```
A_sorted =
     9     1
     9     1
     9     2
     9     3
     8     1
     8     2
     7     2
     7     3
     6     3
```

Comment: sorry, but repelem? it is Undefined function !

Comment: i am using Matlab R2014b

Comment: it is working now, but it still not correct answer, the answer for index by rows should be = 1 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 3

Comment: sorry for extended discussion, but it is still not the answer, as i mentioned below it should be 1 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 3 . Thx